# Clients not receiving events in Socket.IO

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io

I have this simple chat room here:

> app.js

```
const app = require('express')();
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);
const fs = require('fs');

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    var messages;
    fs.readFile('log.txt', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
        messages = data.split('|/');
        for (i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
            socket.emit('message', messages[i]);
        }
        if (err) throw err;
    })
    socket.on('message', function(data) {
        fs.appendFile('log.txt',
            '<span class="seen">' + data.name + ': ' + data.msg + '</span>' + '|/',
            function(err) {
            if (err) throw err;
        })
        socket.broadcast.emit('message', data);
    })
})

http.listen(2099, function(){
    console.log('litening on :2099');
});
```

> index.HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<html>
<head>
<title>chat</title>
<style>
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    background: #404040;
}
input[type=text],[type=submit] {
    font-size: 18px;
}
#chatList {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#inputContainer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 10px;
}
#input {
    width: calc(90% - 40px);
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-right: -3px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    background: #404040;
}
#submit {
    border: 1px white solid;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 11px 2.2%;
    color: white;
    background-color: #404040;
}
.msg {
    margin: 0 12px 0px 12px;
    padding: 12px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
    color: white;
}
.income {
    color: crimson;
}
.sender {
    color: cyan;
}
</style>
 </head>
</head>
<body>
<div id='chat'>
<ul id='chatList'>
</ul>
</div>
<div id='inputContainer'>
<input type="text" id='input' placeholder="Type a message..." autocomplete="off">
<input type="submit" id='submit' value="Send" onclick="send()">
</div>
</form>
<script src='/socket.io/socket.io.js'></script>
<script>
document.getElementById('input').value = '';
var socket = io();
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        send();
    }
})
function send() {
    value = document.getElementById('input').value;
    if (value != '') {
        socket.emit('message', {msg: value, name: username})
        var list = document.getElementById('chatList');
        var msg = document.createElement('li');
        msg.className = 'msg';
        msg.innerHTML = '<span class="sender">' + username + '</span>' + ': ' + value;
        list.appendChild(msg);
        document.getElementById('input').value = '';
    }
}
socket.on('message', function(data) {
    var list = document.getElementById('chatList');
    var msg = document.createElement('li');
    msg.className = 'msg';
    msg.innerHTML = data;
    list.appendChild(msg);
})
document.getElementById('input').value = '';
var username = prompt('Choose a username:');
if (username == '') {
    username = 'mysteryman' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

So this function:

```
fs.readFile('log.txt', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
        messages = data.split('|/');
        for (i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
            socket.emit('messages', messages[i]);
        }
        if (err) throw err;
    })
```

Were suppose to read data from **`log.txt`** and send it as events for the clients to load in old messages. Its working okay but the client side is not receiving any events even though this loop is running and sending events.

I have tried making sure that all events are loaded before sending the data.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Are you sure `messages` event has been trigged? Maybe log.txt is empty. You need check `if (err) throw err;` before use `data` variable. Why do you know client does not receive any message?

Comment: @hoangdv I `console.log` every time the loop run to make sure that its working. `log.txt` is not empty either

Comment: hmm, I think your client side had some errors, let open developer tool of browser, it maybe help you to find the solution.

Comment: @hoangdv its perfectly clean :( im really confused right now

Comment: I am going to clone your code to my local....

Answer (score 1):

Your typo mistake, you emit `messages` event on server side, but listen to `message` (without `s`) event on client side.

Comment: Fixed but still it isnt working. Also really appreciate what you are doing, keep it up man :)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is when the server fires the socket.emit('message'...,  the socket in the client has not been registered yet the socket.on('message'...

Comment: Sadly, it wasn't. I added a event that only fires when all the other event are loaded (the end of script) and only activate the file reading then but still it is not working.